# Interpretation of HTML tag in XML and XSL files

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am using AngularJS, XML, XSL and HTML5.

**This is my XML:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="index.xsl"?>
 <methods xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="generalMethod_Type.xsd">
    <persona>
        <creation_file>
            <creator_name>My name is John</creator_name>
            <file_name>file_name0</file_name>
            <date_creation>2006-05-04T18:13:51.0</date_creation>
        </creation_file>
     </persona>
```

I would like to have "JOHN" in italic (with the `<i>` HTML tag) in order to display it in the browser like this:

```
What's your name? My name is *John*
```

This is a simplified part of the index.xsl where I call the value of `<creator_name>`:

```
<div>
What's your name? <xsl:value-of select="//creator_name"/>
</div>
```

I would like to put the `<i>` tag in the XML in the following way:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="index.xsl"?>
<methods xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="generalMethod_Type.xsd">
    <persona>
        <creation_file>
            <creator_name>My name is <i>John</i></creator_name>
            <file_name>file_name0</file_name>
            <date_creation>2006-05-04T18:13:51.0</date_creation>
        </creation_file>
     </persona>
```

But it is not allowed as `<creator_name>` doesn't have `<i>` children and the browser doesn't interprete it.

Do you have any ideas for this issue?

Comment: You should put your complete XML and XSL source.

Answer (score 2):

You should use CSS.

**index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="index.css"?>
<title>This is the <i>TITLE</i></title>
```

**index.css**

```
i {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: So that's mean that I have put in my XSD, from which my XML depends on, `<i>` tags unbounded?

Comment: You can style your XML element as you want. CSS is much better than XSL, don't worry. :)